# Entity Framework nested class over WCF not showing

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with EF when I need to return nested class.

I have a classic Parent-Child relation

```
create table Orders
(
    OrderID int not null primary key,
    OrderDate DateTime,
    ShipCountry varchar(100) not null
)

create table OrderDetails
(
    OrderID int not null references Orders (OrderID),
    ProductID int not null references Products (ProductID),
    UnitPrice decimal,
    Quantity int,
    constraint PK_OrderDetails primary key (OrderID, ProductID)
)..."
```

I used POCO creator and ended with classes

```
// Orders
    [DataContract]
    public class Order
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; } // OrderID (Primary key)

        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = false)]
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; } // OrderDate

        [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
        public string ShipCountry { get; set; } // ShipCountry


        // Reverse navigation
        public  ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; } // Many to many mapping

        public Order()
        {
            OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
        }
    }

    // OrderDetails
    [DataContract]
    public class OrderDetail
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; } // OrderID (Primary key)

        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; } // ProductID (Primary key)

        [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = false)]
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; } // UnitPrice

        [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = false)]
        public int? Quantity { get; set; } // Quantity


        // Foreign keys
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; } // FK__OrderDeta__Order__173876EA
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; } // FK__OrderDeta__Produ__182C9B23
    }
```

I using MVC4 API controller to provide result ....

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Order> Get(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                var t = db.Orders.Include("OrderDetails").Where(p => p.OrderId > id).ToList();

                return t;
            }
        }
```

the result what I get is

```
<ArrayOfOrder xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/North">
<Order>
<OrderId>2</OrderId>
<OrderDate>2007-02-02T00:00:00</OrderDate>
<ShipCountry>Spain</ShipCountry>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderId>3</OrderId>
<OrderDate>2007-03-03T00:00:00</OrderDate>
<ShipCountry>Spain</ShipCountry>
</Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

AND it makes me crazy...Because I want that OrderDetails be include in response

Like

```
<ArrayOfOrder xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/North">
<Order>
<OrderId>2</OrderId>
<OrderDate>2007-02-02T00:00:00</OrderDate>
<ShipCountry>Spain</ShipCountry>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderId>3</OrderId>
<OrderDate>2007-03-03T00:00:00</OrderDate>
<ShipCountry>Spain</ShipCountry>
   <OrderDetails>
      <OrderId >..</OrderId>
       ......
      <Quantity>..</Quantity>
   </OrderDetails>
</Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

Dont understand ...?!? Am I missing something or.....?

And the strange thing is that in debugger on controller level I see the info about OrderDetails

[image]

So EF provide all class type that I need , but it seams it not goes trough serializer ...

HELP....

Comment: You seem to be confusing WCF with WebApi.. And these are not nested classes.  nested classes are where the classes are defined within another class, which is not the case here.  You probably shouldn't make the Order property virtual if you're not going to use lazy loading.  - Your comments on the OrderDetails collection are confusing, as it's definitely not a many to many, it's a one to many.

Comment: @Erik: Thanks for your help , I managed it to work.About virtual property -> it cam as result of POCO generator, it wasn't me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your DataContract does not define a DataMember attribute on your OrderDetails collection.  So OrderDetails will not be serialized.

Each property in a DataContract that is to be serialized must have a DataMember attribute.

Comment: Yes , this is correct answer, don't know how I missed that , probably was in my blind spot... Marked as answered...Thanks Erik

Comment: @lpastor - ummm.. you did?